# What is the CSS method in arima command?

Tags: r

I am using ARIMA model to fit a time series data. The command `arima` in R works like a charm. Since I am dealing with a fairly large data set with 15831 observations, I used

```
arima(x, order=c(58), method="CSS")
```

instead of `method="CSS-ML"` or `method="ML"`. Now I am finishing the analysis and starting to write a paper. I realized that I could not find enough reference for the "CSS" method. I am wondering if anyone could direct me to the right direction.

Thank you very much.

Sam

Answer (score 1):

CSS = conditional sum of squares, from documentation [LINK](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/arima.html)

> Conditional sum-of-squares is provided mainly for expositional
>   purposes. This computes the sum of squares of the fitted innovations
>   from observation n.cond on, (where n.cond is at least the maximum lag
>   of an AR term), treating all earlier innovations to be zero. Argument
>   n.cond can be used to allow comparability between different fits. The
>   ‘part log-likelihood’ is the first term, half the log of the estimated
>   mean square. Missing values are allowed, but will cause many of the
>   innovations to be missing.

Comment: Hi @Maciej,Thanks a lot for the answer. In a sense, the CSS is to find a least squares solution conditional on the assumption that the first, say `p` observations are exact. This reminds me the Burg's algorithm in fitting an AR model. Thus, I would image that to fit an pure AR model with Burg's algorithm through `ar(sunspot.year, order.max=9, method="burg")` would be similar to `arima(sunspot.year, order=c(9, 0, 0), method="CSS")`. But it turns out that the fitted results are not quite close. Any idea what is the reason? Thanks in advance.